# Can someone confirm if my answer is right?( complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm fairly new to complex numbers and there wasn't much I could find online but could someone see if my answer is right? we need to find $z = a+bi$  given that $z^2 = -144+12i\sqrt{8}$

for LHS:

$$z^2 = (a+bi)^2 = a^2 + 2abi - b^2$$

$$a^2 +2abi - b^2 = -144+12i\sqrt{8}$$

equating real numbers : $$a^2 - b^2 = -144$$

equating imaginary numbers : $$2ab = 12\sqrt{8}$$

solving simultaneously gives

$$a = +1.4 \text{ or } -1.4 \\   
 b = +12.1 \text{ or } -12.1 $$

hence $z = 1.4 + 12.1i  \text{ or } z = -1.4 - 12.1i$

Comment: Why have you quoted decimal approximations of the results instead of using exact [surds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surd_(mathematics))?

Comment: I was mainly focusing on my method so didnt really pay attention to that :)

Comment: yes. your method looks correct!

Comment: There are no “complex numbers in polar form” in your question.

Comment: oh my bad, thats the next part of the question but I dont have any problem in that

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation are correct, in fact $a,b$ are solutions to the following system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a^2-b^2=-144
\\ 2ab=12\sqrt{8}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
From here, it's very easy to see that the solutions are: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a=\frac{7}{5}
\\ b=\frac{30\sqrt{8}}{7}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
and: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a=-\frac{7}{5}
\\ b=-\frac{30\sqrt{8}}{7}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
As a general rule, I don't advise you to trunc the solutions, but write:
$$z_1=\frac{7}{5}+\frac{30\sqrt{8}}{7}i \: \vee \: z_2=-\frac{7}{5}-\frac{30\sqrt{8}}{7}i$$